# Rewrite standard left button on top bar for stacks on React-native-navigation v2

Tags: stack, react-native-navigation-v2

I am using stacks with wix-react-native-navigation. 
When the user press the return button, I need to check the values on the screen and prevent the pop.
Is there any way to rewrite the standard behavior for this return button or I need to replace for a custom one?

Comment: I only managed it by replacing the left button with custom component.